# Component showing products in 3D, to integrate into my webapp

Tags: library, javascript, html, 3d, user-interface

I am looking for a web-app where by, I can have a 360 degrees view (rotations) of a product like a smartphone and be able to select a color and view the device in that color as well as other customizations.

This will be developed with mobile compatibility in mind throw a responsive UI in which compatible plugins/applications would greatly be appreciated.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want a JavaScript/HTML library to integrate into your website, or a full webapp?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I am looking for a way to integrate customizable 3D product models into a webapp that I want to create.

Comment: Customers should be able to rotate the product I guess? Must it work on smartphones too? (no mouse)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Yes, rotations should be allowed and the site will be responsive.

Comment: Please edit your question to add this vital information, thanks! Comments will be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Blend4Web](https://www.blend4web.com/en/) is a plugin for [Blender 3D](https://www.blender.org/) modelling tool that allows exporting models to web formats for viewing in a web browser or integrating into a websites.

It can export in fully self contained HTML file or json format for embedding with a standalone player.

It is frequently used for product visualization and customization, and can be configured to allow material and color changes

All this can mostly be achieved with a a fully GUI workflow through Blender interface. There is a node-based logic editor for controlling basic actions and interactivity without the need for coding. For more advanced features scripting will be required, you can achieve further customization through scripting in JavaScript language.

[Verge3D](https://www.soft8soft.com/) is a similar application (possibly forked from the former) that allows for equivalent functionality compatible with both Blender and Autodesk 3DS Max.

Have in mind that this are full authoring tools to create your own 3D models and applications from scratch; and will require investing time and effort to learn the tools. These are not deploy-ready shopping apps, pre-made product models nor ready to use asset customization templates.

Comment: Would you mind posting a screenshot showing an example of resulting HTML (product + controls) produced by Blend4Web? Thanks!

Comment: Controls are mostly absent, with a minimal approach to UI. Other than that color pickers and customization tools are user created, so appearances will vary